# Blender GPU Rendering Rig -- Configuration

Tags: gpu, rendering, blender

So I currently own a set of GeForce 1060 GPUs (12 units), that I wanted to set up in a GPU RIG for Blender, but I have so many questions. Maybe you guys can help me figure out a few things:

1. Does it make sense to have a 12 unit Render RIG for Blender by any means, or is this crazy stupid, because Blender can't handle that much GPU by some limitations I am not aware of?
2. How much RAM and CPU would I need to align perfectly with the GPUs and have a decent Blender environment?
3. Does it make sense to buy one of those Mining Motherboards, that have like 20 PCIe slots, so that I can run those GPU units?
4. What SSD would you prefer?
5. What OS should I use? (I am currently on Mac --> so would I go for Windows or Linux (which Linux))?

Thank you so much for helping me out. All the best, André

Answer (score 2):

If your looking on CUDA Cores which help the speed of rendering, a GTX 1080 is a good choice. But if you don't want to spend much, a GTX 1660 Super is a great bang for the buck. A GTX 1660 Super is around £200-300.

However, a very good, high-end AMD GPU for around £280 pound is an RX 5600xt.

A good SSD would be a Kingston or a Western Digital SSD; those are good staring points.

DO NOT BUY MULTI GPU, as spending money on one high-end GPU is better than two mediocre GPUs.

Windows has more stability then Linux.

Around 16gb ram is good, but you could get 32 if you want.

A CPU to pair with an RX 5600xt is a Ryzen 5 2600x or a 3600x.

Comment: Wow great answer.